# apache 2.4 exclude url

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, htpasswd

I need to configure apache in reverse proxy to have all url protected with password except url start with /app/test#/toto/xxxxx. I have a problem with the # in the url, if I test with other url without # and change the pattern it's ok.

That's my configuration

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentification pour l'accès"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/passwd/passwords"
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m|^/app/test#/toto/.*|
    Require valid-user
</Location>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:601/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:601/
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: # means comment try to escape it with \ it should loo like `^/app/test/\#/toto.*|`

Comment: I have edit my post I have made a mistake on the url. I have tried with \ to escape but it's not working

Comment: Can you try to define the location as https://pastebin.com/NJE2CXq9